# A sketcpad app with a capabilty to export an inkml file

Tags: android, drawing

I'm interested in installing a simple sketch app on my ebook-reader (an android device) with the capability to save/export an [inkml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InkML) file. so all strokes will get stored for each sketch I have drawn.

I have searched and installed few apps and didn't find any app with this feature. Is there an android app which offers this kind of functionality ?

Thank you!